# Music plays only one time from server in online music player

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer

I designed an online music player which streams file from my server and shows them in a recyclerView. when I click on the specific song it plays automatically, but when I go back to my recyclerview and I choose it again it doesn't play anymore and even duration of song becomes an insane number. I even tried to handle my media player `onBackPressed()` method or in `OnRestart()` or `onResume()` method. I'm confused. Please let me know about any suggestion.

Here's my code for player:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private CircularMusicProgressBar cover;
private ImageButton playPause, rewind, forward, repeat, fav, download;
private TextView title, term, spendingTime, totalTime, emptyRec;
private Context context;
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int i;
private Timer timer;
private Bundle extra;
Uri uri;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
SuggestionAdapter suggestionAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
List<Listening> list = new ArrayList<>();
String url = "https://www.learnhere.ir/listening.php";
AccessDataOnServer suggestionData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    initFields();
    playOnStart();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_pause:
            if (i == 1) {
                i = 2;
                playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                i = 1;
                playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause);
                int b = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(b);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rewind:
            Toast.makeText(context, "rewind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.forward:
            Toast.makeText(context, "forward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.repeat:
            Toast.makeText(context, "repeat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.fav:
            Toast.makeText(context, "fav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.download:
            Toast.makeText(context, "download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

public void initFields() {
    i = 0;
    context = this;
    cover = findViewById(R.id.cover_progress);
    playPause = findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
    rewind = findViewById(R.id.rewind);
    forward = findViewById(R.id.forward);
    repeat = findViewById(R.id.repeat);
    fav = findViewById(R.id.fav);
    download = findViewById(R.id.download);
    title = findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
    term = findViewById(R.id.term_tv);
    emptyRec = findViewById(R.id.empty_rec);
    spendingTime = findViewById(R.id.spending_time);
    totalTime = findViewById(R.id.total_time);

    playPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    rewind.setOnClickListener(this);
    forward.setOnClickListener(this);
    repeat.setOnClickListener(this);
    fav.setOnClickListener(this);
    download.setOnClickListener(this);
    extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    Picasso.get().load(extra.getString("cover")).into(cover);
    title.setText(extra.getString("title"));
    term.setText(extra.getString("term"));
    timer = new Timer();
    uri = Uri.parse(extra.getString("link"));
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.suggestion_recycler);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    suggestionAdapter = new SuggestionAdapter(list, context);
    suggestionData = new AccessDataOnServer();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(suggestionAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    suggestionData.getSuggestion(context, list, recyclerView, url, requestQueue);

    if (list.size() <= 1) {
        emptyRec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        emptyRec.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void play() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                        new AudioAttributes
                                .Builder()
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                                .build());
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        getTime();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

public void playOnStart() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait until the audio plays...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    play();
    i = 1;
    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause);
}

public String millisecondToSecond(long millisecond) {
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondString = "";
    String minuteString = "";
    //convert total duration into time
    int hour = (int) (millisecond / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minute = (int) (millisecond % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
    int second = (int) (millisecond % (1000 * 60 * 60) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    //Add hours if there
    if (hour > 0) {
        finalTimerString = hour + ":";
    }
    //Prepending 0 to second if it's one digit
    if (second < 10) {
        secondString = "0" + second;
    } else {
        secondString = "" + second;
    }
    //Prepending 0 to minute if it's one digit
    if (minute < 10) {
        minuteString = "0" + minute;
    } else {
        minuteString = "" + minute;
    }
    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minuteString + ":" + secondString;
    //Return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}

public void getTime() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Without runOnUiThread we don't have access to modifiers like text view
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long current = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    int i = (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100) / mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    spendingTime.setText("" + millisecondToSecond(current));
                    cover.setValue(i);

                    int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    String time = String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
                    totalTime.setText(time);


                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    playOnStart();
}
```

Comment: @chand mohd any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I reviewed your codes and it seems you aren't using Media player class properly.
I made a few changes to each block of your codes. I hope it solves your problem.

First of all change the following scope:

```
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

**To**

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

I made a method for your `mediaPlayer` and you should use it in your `onCreate()` :

```
private void prepareMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        updateSeekBarTimer();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

A method to update your `seekbar` :

```
private void updateSeekBarTimer() {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            total_time = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            current_time = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            totalTime.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(total_time));
            spendingTime.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(current_time));
            int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(current_time, total_time));
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateSeekBarTimer();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally you need an Interface to decide what happens when your track ends:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener


 @Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play);
    if (rep) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause);
        updateSeekBarTimer();

    } else {
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        totalTime.setText(R.string.zero_time);
        spendingTime.setText(R.string.zero_time);
        playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        prepareMediaPlayer();
    }
}
```